# C# INotifyPropertyChanged UWP Win10

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Такой момент , пишу приложение для Windows Phone, нужно передать данные с одной страницы на другую, Frame и OnNavigateonTO использовать возможности нет , нужно через PropertyChanged.
Собственное проблема в том что PropertyChanged не замечает изменение в Enter и не обновляет данные в MainPage , собственно именно на эту страницу мне и нужно их передать ...
когда происходят изменение на странице Enter, то они переходят в класс MenuItem , но не изменяется значение на странице MainPage

!!!!!!!!MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 ...<TextBlock x:Name="NameWorker" Text="{x:Bind demomenuViewModel.Welcom, Mode=OneWay}" />....

 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        demomenuViewModel demomenuViewModel = new demomenuViewModel();      
....
```

!!!!!!Enter.xaml.cs

```
    public sealed partial class Enter : Page
    {
        private demomenuViewModel VM = new demomenuViewModel();

        private void enter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {                                 
             VM.Welcom = login.nameuser.ToString();                                                                                  
        }  
      ...
     }
```

!!! MenuItem.cs

```
public class demomenuViewModel : asyncViewModel
    {
      ...
        public string Welcom
        {
            get
            { return welcom; }
            set
            {
                welcom = value;
                INotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
     ...
}
```

Comment: Уберите весь лишний код, и продемонстрируйте проблему на завершённом примере. [mcve]

Comment: @VladD так понятней ?

Comment: Окей, а что непонятно? У вас два различных экземпляра `demomenuViewModel`, понятно, что данные в них никак не связаны.

Comment: Да , это я уже тоже понял , пытался сделать через '`statik`', также не вышло , ибо функция '`INotifyPropertyChanged`' не работает как статик .... Возможно можете подсказать какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Например, скармливать страницам (`MainPage` и `Enter`) **один и тот же экземпляр** `demomenuViewModel` в конструкторе?

Comment: Или сохранять значение в настройках и считывать его